# SSRS How to generate random color for chart elements

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS SQL Server 2017 and cannot find any indication online as to how to achieve random colors on charts.

I know there used to be a to achieve this on SSRS 2008R2 using custom code as some of our reports used to have charts with random colors.

Unfortunately the colour code in the charts was removed when we moved to SSRS 2017 as it threw errors. Now the users would like it back.

Any help in finding a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be useful to see the code that was removed so it's easier to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you sure you want **random** colors?

Comment: Alan, I wish I could publish the code and reverse engineer it. Unfortunately it was stripped out by a third party, no longer with us (changed job, not deceased).

We have dynamic bar charts with variable numbers of columns, hence the need for random colours, however, I see your point; 'random' and 'dynamic' are not the same thing. I mean dynamic. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Cracked it for anyone else wishing to dynamically add multiple colors to charts etc.

Start by referencing the .NET assembly 'System.Drawing'. This allows us to read and convert colors from RGB to HTML.

Right click on your SSRS report.

Go to properties > References.

Add a new reference (by browsing using [...])

There are three tabs, use the .NET one. In there you will find 'System.Drawing'. Select it and hit [OK].

Next we add some custom code (a function). The function basically created a random RGB colour reference and then we convert it to a SSRS friendly format:

Do this by right clicking on your SSRS report again.

Go to properties > Code.

Add this:

```
Public Shared Function GenerateRandomColor(ByVal seed As Integer) As String 
Dim randNum As New Random(seed) 
Return System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml( _ 
System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb( _ 
randNum.Next(0, 255), _ 
randNum.Next(0, 255), _ 
randNum.Next(0, 255))) 
End Function
```

Hit [OK] when you are done.

Next we need to call the function to fill the chart.
Right click on the chart and select 'Series Properties'

Go to 'Fill' and hit the [fx] button to add an expression.

Paste the following code:

```
=Code.GenerateRandomColor(RunningValue(Fields!Description.Value,Count,Nothing))
```

You are done! Your chart will now look like a veritable rainbow, no matter how many columns your data produces.

Comment: When I click on 3 dots I get Documents folder open. How can I find where System.Drawing is?